# Azure API Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-apps, azure-management-api

I am using Azure API's in C# code and used below libraries:

```cs
using Microsoft.Rest; using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Analytics;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Analytics.Models;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

To create connection with Azure:

```cs
private static ServiceClientCredentials AuthenticateAzure(string domainName, string nativeClientAppCLIENTID)
{
    // User login via interactive popup
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
    // Use the client ID of an existing AAD "Native Client" application.
    var activeDirectoryClientSettings = ActiveDirectoryClientSettings.UsePromptOnly(nativeClientAppCLIENTID, new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
    return UserTokenProvider.LoginWithPromptAsync(domainName, activeDirectoryClientSettings).Result;
}
```

When calling `LoginWithPromptAsync`, I got the popup, which ask my credentials. I don't want this pop-up to appear every time I run the code. Is there any way to come up with this thing beside creating Azure app?

I have an `ApplicationId`, `TenantId`, `CertificateThumbprint`, and `SubscriptionId` (below).  Can I use these fields to authenticate to azure without prompt?

[image: example of credentials]

Comment: There are instructions here as to how to create ServicePrinicpal to do this http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/12/calling-arm-using-plain-rest.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the function `UserTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(nativeClientAppClientid, domainName, userName, password)` to get our credentials without pop-up. It works fine for me, the following is my  test code. How to registry WebApp please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-integrating-applications#adding-an-application).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var certificate = AuthenticateAzure("your domain name", "Ad App client ID", "username", "password");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Log in to azure active directory in non-interactive mode using organizational
    //   id credentials and the default token cache. Default service settings (authority,
    //   audience) for logging in to azure resource manager are used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domainName"> The active directory domain or tenant id to authenticate with</param>
    /// <param name="nativeClientAppClientid">  The active directory client id for this application </param>
    /// <param name="userName"> The organizational account user name, given in the form of a user principal name  (e.g. user1@contoso.org).</param>
    /// <param name="password"> The organizational account password.</param>
    /// <returns>A ServiceClientCredentials object that can be used to authenticate http requests  using the given credentials.</returns>
    private static ServiceClientCredentials AuthenticateAzure(string domainName, string nativeClientAppClientid,string userName,string password)
    {
       return UserTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(nativeClientAppClientid, domainName, userName, password).Result;
    }
```

[image]

**Update:**

More details steps about how to registry AD App and assign role to application, please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application).
After that we can get `tenantId, appId, secretKey` from the Azure Portal. Then we can use [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) SDK to get token for api authentication.

Demo code:

```
var subscriptionId = "Your subscrption";
var appId = "Registried Azure Application Id";
var secretKey = "Secret Key";
var tenantId = "tenant Id";
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey );
var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/");
    // Now we can party with our HttpClient!
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Azure API's for ADLS file access and for some file manipulation and want to integrate with U-SQL project. What would be the "domain name" in that case? Secondly. I don't want to register an app on Azure portal.

Comment: Azure also allow to use self-signed management certificate  or Azure AD to get authentication. More info about Windows Azure Management Certificates please refer to  [document](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/windows-azure-management-certificates/).  domain name: `By default, a basic domain name at .onmicrosoft.com is included with your directory. Later, you can add a domain name that your organization already uses, such as contoso.com.`

Comment: I have application ID, TenantId and other thing. Will this help me to authenticate to azure without prompt. I have edited my question and attached one image.. Can you please help me on this line.. Thanks...

Comment: Thanks for your effort... I am using your code as is with AcquireTokenAsync function. As the method is async, control doesn't reach to the next line "var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;" or does not generate any authentication error....

Comment: Hi Ajay, `var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result` should let us get the tokenResponse.

Comment: Hi Tom, I need `ServiceClientCredentials` object at the end to instantiate `DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient`. I have to access ADLS file system for some file manipulation. For above problem, as we are using async method we have to use `var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Hi Tom.. ur code is working fine with console application and I am able to create DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient object with following code `ServiceClientCredentials creds = new TokenCredentials(tokenResponse.AccessToken); DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);` but when I am trying to do any  `_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.GetFileStatus(_adlsAccountN‌​ame, Path.Combine(folderPath, fname));` , it return `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.Models.AdlsErrorException`

Comment: hi Ajay, if want to get credential for SDK to init `DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient` object, then we can do it easy with `var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, applicationId, secretKey).Result;`
            `var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);`. About AdlsErrorExpection, please refer to your another [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330313/azure-adlserror-webhdfs-error-while-deleting-adls-file)

Comment: I added my role as "Data Lake Analytics Developer" role and everything is working fine... Thanks Tom for your effort. Can you help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330565/u-sql-error-while-using-reference-assembly?noredirect=1