# Azure - ADlsError / WebHDFS error while deleting ADLS file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-api-apps

I am using C# for ADLS authentication and wants to do some file operation like delete, rename. Using below code for authentication and delete operation

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/");
}

ServiceClientCredentials creds = new TokenCredentials(tokenResponse.AccessToken);// tokenResponse.IdToken, tokenResponse.AccessTokenType);

DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);

_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Delete(_adlsAccountName, FilenameWPath);
```

I am getting AdlsError,

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.Models.AdlsErrorException'
>   occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe

which mean WebHDFS should be enabled? How to enable webHDFS on ADLS. I checked the HDInight, webHDFS is enabled.

Please let me know, How I can rectify this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  we don't assgin permission for our file then we will have no permission to operate the file. If it is that case, please refer to my demo. The following is my detail steps and sample code. It works correctly for me.

**Assign permission for the file on the Azure portal.**

1.In our Data Lake Store account blade, click Data Explorer

[image]

2.click the file or folder for which you want to provide access to the Azure AD application, and then click Access
[image]

3.Add "assign permission" ,in Select User or Group blade, look for the Azure Active Directory application you created earlier. 
[image]
4.select appropriate permission
[image]
5.Check the file has got permission
[image]

Demo Code:

```
 var applicationId = "Application Id";
 var secretKey = "Secret Key";
 var tenantId = "Tenant Id";
 var adlsAccountName = "ADLS Account Name";
 var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, applicationId, secretKey).Result;
 var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
 var status = adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.GetFileStatus(adlsAccountName, "/mytempdir/myinputfile.txt");
 var deletResult = adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Delete(adlsAccountName, "/mytempdir/myinputfile.txt");
```

Delete file

[image]

Get file status

[image]

Comment: I added my role as "Data Lake Analytics Developer" role and everything is working fine... Thanks Tom for your effort. Can you help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330565/u-sql-error-while-using-reference-assembly?noredirect=1