# How to submit a U-SQL job and get the status of the job with Azure SDK Azure.ResourcesManager.DatalakeAnalytics?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Previous answer from stack overflow shows the uses of SDK `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Analytics`
But this nuget has been deprecated and the alternative is `Azure.ResourcesManager.DatalakeAnalytics`.
The previous client `DataLakeAnalyticsjobManagementClient` is not available in the new nuget or atleast I am not able to use it.

Comment: **Previous answer from stack overflow** - Could you share the link here?

Comment: @Aswin  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027317/submit-a-u-sql-job-using-net-sdk