# How to Append a File using Web HDFS REST API in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure, hadoop

I am using **Azure Data Lake** to upload the file before but still want to append the text file content existing Data Lake text file. Is there any option available to append the text file data using **Web HDFS REST API** in C#?.

I am refer this link [enter link description here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Append_to_a_File)

**Code:** I Can refer the above link get the append URL. But how can i use this URL and Append a File using c#?

```
private const string AppendUrl = "https://{0}.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/{1}?&op=APPEND&noredirect=true";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Rest Api to do that we could  use the following code. I test it with Postman.

```
private const string AppendUrl = "https://{datalakeName}.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/{filepath}?append=true&op=APPEND&api-version=2016-11-01"
var token = "eyJ0eX.....";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
     var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
     var data = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

[image]

We also could use the Azure [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store) to do that. How to get the application id and secretkey you could refer to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application). More detail steps to get the permission to access the datalake you could refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330313/azure-adlserror-webhdfs-error-while-deleting-adls-file/41341205#41341205).

```
var applicationId = "application Id";
var secretKey = "secretKey";
var tenantId = "tenant id";
var adlsAccountName = "datalake account name";
var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, applicationId, secretKey).Result;
var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds,clientTimeoutInMinutes:60);
var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\tom\testtext.txt");
var test = adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.AppendWithHttpMessagesAsync(adlsAccountName, "test/abc.txt", stream).Result;
```

[image]

packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store" version="2.3.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader" version="1.0.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.2-beta1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: The Rest Api Code Works for me. Thanks you very much@Tom Sun