# Upload file to Azure Datalake Store from local using Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-java-sdk

Is there any way to upload files from local to ADLS using Java SDK? I have tried using the following code to upload but the code is not getting compiled as it says the constructor is not visible.

```
com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.Utils ut=new com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.Utils(adlStoreclient);

ut.upload(filePathToUpload, fileToUpload, IfExists.OVERWRITE);
```

Comment: Did you check the official [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-lake-store-java-upload-download-get-started)? Because your code snippet differs a lot from the provided sample....

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk), there are create,list,delete methods etc. except `upload` and `download` method in Java SDK.

Then I searched the [Azure Data Lake java sdk source code](https://azure.github.io/azure-data-lake-store-java/javadoc/) , it also doesn't seem to contain `upload` and `download` method in `ADLStoreClient` Class.

Based on this situation, I suggest you using REST API to upload file to ADL.

You need to follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-rest-api) to upload data into ADL via REST API. How to get the application id and secretkey you could refer to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application). More detail steps to get the permission to access the datalake you could refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330313/azure-adlserror-webhdfs-error-while-deleting-adls-file/41341205#41341205).

Get Access Token sample code:

```
private static String clientId = "***";
private static String authTokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token";
private static String clientKey = "***";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AccessTokenProvider provider = new ClientCredsTokenProvider(authTokenEndpoint, clientId, clientKey);
        String accessToken=provider.getToken().accessToken;
}
```

Then use this [Upload Data](http://private%20static%20String%20clientId%20=%20%223ca38c93-85fc-426f-a870-2a074b16e10f%22;%20%20%20%20%20private%20static%20String%20authTokenEndpoint%20=%20%22https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/oauth2/token%22;%20%20%20%20%20private%20static%20String%20clientKey%20=%20%22UnwKpB714aWF/yLVQHJ4Y8kkA6ErjxfrOUhuyCTOCnE=%22;%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20static%20void%20main(String[]%20args)%20throws%20IOException%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AccessTokenProvider%20provider%20=%20new%20ClientCredsTokenProvider(authTokenEndpoint,%20clientId,%20clientKey);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20String%20accessToken=provider.getToken().accessToken;) steps to upload your local file into ADL.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue.
The SDK provides a method to upload files like I mentioned in my question. Also, I had mentioned that the constructor was not visible. So, I found the upload methods from the sdk here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/datalake/store/Utils.java) and implemented the same concept to stream the data to ADLS from my local file.