# U-SQL Error while using REFERENCE ASSEMBLY

Tags: c#, azure, u-sql

I created a U-SQL library using Azure APIs and register the assembly on Azure cloud with all dependencies. I added this library with my U-SQL project and added below line On my U-SQL script

```
USE master;
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [AzureLibrary];
```

At the time of using functions or methods I created in library, I got below error message.

> Inner exception from user expression: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Current row
>   dump: result: "zzz"

Please help, I tried several ways but the same message appears every time.

======================================

I am using below code

```
public static int DelTest()
        {
            int Retval = 1;
            try
            {
                var secretKey = <secret key>;
                var appId = <app id>;
                var tenantId = <tenant id>;
                string _adlsAccountName = <adls account name>;
                DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient _adlsFileSystemClient;

                var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
                ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
                var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
                var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/");
                    // Now we can party with our HttpClient!
                }

                ServiceClientCredentials creds = new TokenCredentials(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
                DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient _adlsClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(creds);
                _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Delete(_adlsAccountName, "/raw_files/sls_tty_typ.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Retval = 0;
                throw;
            }
            return Retval;
        }
```

I register it using "Register Assembly"

[image]

I used below code in U-SQL script

```
USE [master];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [USQLCSharpProject1];

@ext =
    EXTRACT result string
    FROM "/raw_files/test_file.txt"
    USING Extractors.Csv();

@ext1 =
    SELECT result,
           USQLCSharpProject1.Class1.DelTest() AS del_success FROM @ext;

OUTPUT @ext1
TO "/raw_files/test_file1.txt"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

During execution, I got below error message.

[image]

## Please help me to resolve this issue.

Please find `packages.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Analytics" version="1.0.1-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store" version="1.0.2-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader" version="1.0.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Can you post your entire U-SQL script and the entire error message?

Comment: The error message tells us that the assembly `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store` is missing.  How do you register your assembly? It would be better if you give detailed steps about how to register the assembly.

Comment: Pls see edits....

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, Please check below scenarios:

1) Make sure the assembly's property Copy Local is true:

[image]

2) When Register Assembly, please make sure the Managed Dependencies are selected:

[image]

3) please check bin/Debug folder to make sure this assembly is existed. If the register assembies larger than 15kb, please make sure it is existed in Data Lake store

[image]

Comment: I followed all the steps as you mentioned but still getting the same error message.

Comment: I added all the dependencies during the register assembly but still getting the same error

Comment: If you open packages.config under USQLCSharpProject1, could you find the package ` Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store`? If possible, please try in another project, install the assembly again, then try to see whether you could reproduce this issue. Please do not forget to check all I mentioned in my origin reply.

Comment: please see edits... This is my second project.. In my previous project, I followed the same step and getting the same error. Shall I need to change TargetFramework?

Comment: Have you tried this thing at your end? Is it working fine?

Comment: I was getting an warning `package element is not declared` in package.config, I eliminated it adding `xmlns="urn:packages"` under <packages> node...

Comment: It works fine on my local. Based on your description you have received an warning in the package element. Please try to install Data Lake Store assembly via  running package command `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store -Pre` (Visual Studio -> View -> 'Other Windows' -> Package Manager Console )

Comment: Thanks for your effort... I ran it in ADLA account configured in Azure...

Comment: I created another project and used project manager console to install packages. I followed all your instructions but still getting the same error. I am using ADLA configured in Azure not local.

Comment: I created atleast 5 project and tried different things but getting the same error every time... seems like a bug....

Comment: Maybe it caused by your environment. Could you share me with detailed steps or the tutorials? I will test it with the steps you tried. If this is a bug, I will report it to the related team.

Comment: I already shared u detailed steps... Regarding environment, I am using Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1, 64-bit OS, Intel core i5, 2.40 GHz, 8 GB RAM,  Visual studio Enterprise 2015, version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, .Net Framework - 4.5.2. I am `not` using `local to generate Assembly`.

Comment: Hope this helps you to replicate issue at your end..Please let me know, if more information is required. If you want, we can do a screen sharing session.

Comment: Hi... Any resolution to this issue or is this is a bug?

Comment: Here is the [sample code](https://jaml.blob.core.windows.net/vsdeploy/USQLApplication2.zip) on my side. Please try to compare your project with mine, hope this could give you tips.

Comment: Thanks for ur effort.. Are u running ur U-SQL script in Local mode or with ADLS account?

Answer (score 0):

can you please forward me a repro project and the exact steps you take to usql (at) Microsoft?

Looking at your code above, I have one caveat: I see you try to do a direct HTTP call. The U-SQL vertex mode in ADLA does not allow you to make HTTP calls to avoid accidental DDOS incidents. So even if the registration would work, I am doubtful your code would actually behave as you expect.

What are you trying to achieve?