# Can I programmatically get a list of Azure Service Bus Relays and how many listeners they have?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

Via the Azure Portal, I can see which Relays are connected and how many listeners they have.  I'd like to do this programmatically so that I can know which connections I have and whether or not there is anyone is listening on them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know we can use Rest API to get the  listeners and relays. I test it with fiddler, it works correctly more details please refer to the snapshot.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Relay/namespaces/{namspace}/WcfRelays?api-version=2016-07-01
```

If we want to get a WcfRelay, we need to supply a WcfRelay name.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Relay/namespaces/{namspace}/WcfRelays/{WcfRelayName}?api-version=2016-07-01
```

[image]

Detail info on the Azure portal

[image]

Comment: What do I need to do to get a bearer token for the management api?

Comment: If you use C# code, please refer to another [SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260442/azure-api-authentication?answertab=active#tab-top) to get more info about API Authentication.