# How to create LogicApp SQL Server Connector's API Connection using DotNet SDK

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, connector, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

Here is the steps to connect to a SQL Server or Azure SQL database from Azure Logic apps using the Azure portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure

But, I have to create SQL Server Connector's API Connection using the DotNet SDK.

Comment: Can you clarify.  By .Net SDK, you mean with just c# or such and not a Logic App?

Comment: Yes with C# using .Net SDK

Comment: SQL Server Connector Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I can't find the creating logicApp connector API connection function from [Azure SDK document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260442/azure-api-authentication/41276687#41276687).

If use the Rest API is possible, we could use the following rest API to do that.

```
put https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql?api-version=2016-06-01
```

I also test it on my side with postman with following body.

```
{"properties":{"api":{"id":"/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/sql"},"parameterValues":{"server":"{yourserverName}.database.windows.net","database":"{databaseName}","username":"{username}","password":"{password}"},"displayName":"{name}"},"location":"{location}"}
```

[image]

How to get the authorization token, please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260442/azure-api-authentication/41276687#41276687).

Comment: This is worked. Do you know how to pass table name in request json? Thanks

Comment: Also can you please share the link from where you got this reference. Thanks

Comment: I don't find it in azure document. But I capture the Rest API from Azure portal while I am creating the connector.

Comment: We also could get the related information from ARM template https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-logic-app-sql-proc/azuredeploy.json#L58